# Multi level Interitance

Tags: oop, c#-4.0, inheritance

```
I have three class.
Class A
{
  public void Add()
  {
           //Do-something () 
  }
}
Class B:A
{
//Do-something () 
}
Class C :B
{
 //Do-something () 
}
```

How do I implements these above class , B can't get the Add method from A, but C can get Add method from A.  Could anyone advise , How can I implement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can't be done on the one inheritance chain. This is more of a job for composition. ie:

```
Class C
{
  ClassA classAObject;
  Add() { classAObject.Add(); } 
}
```

Remember, Inheritance is useful when you wish to transfer the entire parent interface to the subclass. When you wish to control that interface in your sub class, it's better to use composition.